# In windows service what is the difference between stop and pause?

Tags: windows, service

When developing Window Service Apps, what is the difference between stop and pause?

Do developers distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When a service is paused, it can maintain internal state, including cached information or possibly even a queue of waiting work items.  The service can then be resumed to pick up where it left off.

If the service is stopped, internal state is discarded.  Starting the service again should repeat all initialization.

Developers do distinguish between the two.  The distinction is very important when a service has a non-trivial initialization process.

For more information on `service states' see [Introduction to Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: The linked "Introduction to Windows Services" has a slight .Net bias; Windows Services can also be native applications. Both types of services share the same state model.

Comment: Stop/Start ~ Process is terminated / new process is started; Pause/Continue ~ Process is not termined and must use internal logic to "pause (or resume) processing" by listening to event signals. So "internal state" ~ "program / execution state".

Comment: Not sure what the "Intorduction to WIndows Services" used to point to, but i do not think it works anymore. Maybe this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications

Comment: @Deczaloth According to the web archive, your link seems to contain the equivalent content ([source](http://web.archive.org/web/20130306153419/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.80).aspx)).